# Download All AEM Logs with no SSH access

Tags: aem

I'm trying to find a way for our devs to be able to download all AEM logs via the Sling or some other means. They do not have SSH access, so can't just jump on the server and download them.

The closest I've found is using /system/console/status-slinglogs and clicking the Download as Zip button. The problem is it only zips up the last 3 days, where as we need all logged days.

Does anyone know of a way to increase the number of days it includes? Or is the another way to do this?

Thanks!
Matt

Comment: Did you talk to the operators of the instance? Perhaps they can provide ssh-keys or additional ways to access the logs.

Comment: slinglog is the door that AEM provides to access logs without access to the server where AEM is hosted. In this case, you have to request them to the proper team